# Regex | How do I target/jump to the next line or a specific line?

Tags: java, regex

I am currently learning how to use regex and I don't know how to access a new line/specific line.
An example: My Text input would look like this:

```
Problem 20 from 100
text for nothing
TargetText Another Text
```

So I know I can get the first line (Problem 20) with:

```
Problem [0-9]{1,3}
```

My question would be: Is it possible to get `TargetText` ? Or is that something I have to fix with my Matcher Class (Java)?

Comment: You are missing a space between Problem and the digits. But you can match the rest of the line and then the whole next line, capturing the first word of the third line. `^Problem\h+[0-9]{1,3}\b.*\R.*\R(\w+)` https://regex101.com/r/xP90ij/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You were missing a space between `Problem` and the digits) You can match the rest of the line and then the whole next line, capturing the first word of the third line in a group.

```
^Problem\h+[0-9]{1,3}\b.*\R.*\R(\w+)
```

- `^Problem\h+` Match `Problem and 1+ spaces at the start of the string
- `[0-9]{1,3}\b` Match 1-3 digits, and a word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `.*\R.*\R` Match the rest of the line, a newline and the same again
- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word chars in **group 1**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xP90ij/1/)

Example code

```
String regex = "^Problem\\h+[0-9]{1,3}\\b.*\\R.*\\R(\\w+)";
String string = "Problem 20 from 100\n"
+ "text for nothing\n"
+ "TargetText Another Text";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
TargetText
```